# Giving positive/negative connotation to two textual options/buttons

Tags: interaction-design, user-behavior, buttons, interface, mobile-application

I'm developing an "photo editor'ish" mobile application.  After the user has finished processing their photo (such as choosing filters, shape, etc), the user should save the outcome to their camera roll.

I'm offering two options:

1. Save for free, with a watermark on the final picture
2. Save without a watermark (if selected, an In App Purchase window pops up).

This is how I've made it look now :

[image: screenshot of buttons saying "export tag free" and "save with pulse tag"]

I would like to increase my In App Purchase rate.  How can I make the first option look positive and be triggered more frequently than the free watermarked option?

**UPDATE**

This is what i went for at the end. I tried to make to top one more positive than the bottom by appending the word "Save" only to the first one –

[image]

Comment: Do users have a preview of both so they can understand the difference between the free and paid version? In addition show the price with the preview and button so people won't get surprised by a purchase dialog.

Comment: Hey @jazZRo , thank you for replying .They do have a preview(above the buttons), which contains a small watermark/tag(i think it's noticeable). And I think leaving out the price of the text, will increase the IAP rate, yes - they aren't expecting it, but its like going to a store and found out a particular grocery costs 1 more dollar(IMO)

Comment: I wouldn't use the world "tag", that has a different meaning than you're implying here (ex: tags in email).  I don't think that your grocery store analogy applies.  When I go to the grocery store, I expect to purchase something. When I'm using a free app, I don't necessarily have that same option.  You are correct in that, like at a grocery store, if an item I wanted to purchase is more than I expected to pay, I can buy a different item (or use a different app) that does meet my expectations.  I would recommend a lot of user testing, especially since you're interested in positive feelings.

Comment: Hey @nadyne. Iv'e changed the two options two : 1)SAVE CLEAN PHOTO ||OR|| 2) WITH WATERMARK. That way the word Save assigned to the first option, and give it a positive reaction, while the second option remain with "WITH WATERMARK" which give's us the negative effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using 'Export' word in red button and 'Save' in text Button?

I see a good approch. 
But Text Button looks very different, I thought it will have different funtionality. 
Both buttons belong to same group.

So design keeping consistency.

[image]

See above, it looks like both are clickable and are buttons.

Comment: Hey ! Thank you for answering! That's a great approach! They question is if the user understand/feel that the upper is the positive and the bottom is the negative?

Comment: @RoiMulia Yes, it will be a positive feeling for the user.

Comment: I've attached an update with my final decision, What do you think? I tried to make to top one more positive than the bottom by appending the word "Save" only to the first one –

Comment: @RoiMulia looks much better. It will work.

Answer (score 1):

1. Using two different words for the export (e.g., export, save) is a little confusing.  It's better to be consistent; make both *export* or both *save*.
2. If you're going to specify *tag free*, separate that from the action.  Here are some formatting alternatives:

   - `EXPORT | TAG FREE` or `EXPORT (TAG FREE)`
   - `EXPORT | WITH TAG` or `EXPORT (WITH TAG)`
3. Watermarks are fairly common and understood - I'm not sure I would understand what a *tag* was.  Consider word choice for what your users may understand best.

Comment: Hey vol. Thank you for your responds! I've attached an update with my final decision, What do you think? I tried to make to top one more positive than the bottom by appending the word "Save" only to the first one

Comment: @RoiMulia I like it! But I'm not sure if the *CLEAN* is necessary as it may be implied, but I was ask others what they think.

Comment: I hear you.. But i couldn't find another title to describe the outcome. I would love to hear new ideas if you have. Trying to bring the positiveness to the first options. CLEAN surely do it, but maybe it's bit off context?

Comment: @RoiMulia I was saying just "SAVE PHOTO" -or- "WITH WATERMARK".  Because the second suggests the photo has been modified, the first suggests it's the original, unadulterated photo.  So I was saying, I think it's implied that it's clean/untouched and thus the word *clean* isn't necessary.

Comment: But it won't imply that it's watermark free maybe? It's sound like two different actions(IMO)

Comment: You're the closest thing to your users.  If it sounds like two different actions, it may be.  The only right answer is what works best for your users/customers.  From what you've shown, I would see them as an associated action, since the "OR" links the two buttons.  I have my opinion, but I'm not standing firm on it.  I'd yield to what others think.

Comment: Yap. It make sense eventually. I'm releasing the app this week, i'll have more resolutions than :)