# Improving textual connotation to buttons

Tags: interaction-design, user-behavior, mobile-application, interactive-ui, customer-experience

I'm developing a "photo editor'sh" app. At the final stage, just before saving the outcome to the camera roll, I'm previewing the outcome to the user(With my own watermark), with two option:

1.Save Without watermark/tag

2.Save With watermark/tag

**The main problem is that "With watermark",sounds positive while the "without watermark" sounds negative.While in the real use-case i want the user to click the option 1(without) - who trigger the In App Purchase window**

Watermark sample :

[image]

Options sample(I've tried to change the text it self, but i don't think it got the desired effect):

In order to focus our problem on **textual content only**,I've added below a new screenshot of the options, in terms of design only(UI),not content.

[image]

**UPDATE**
I've attached an update with my final decision, What do you think? I tried to make to top one more positive than the bottom by appending the word "Save" only to the first one –

[image]

Comment: does the in app purchase remove the watermark from all future photo saves or just that specific photo?

Comment: @DaveHaigh All future photos, it's one time payment, for all the future & current outcomes

Comment: I see what youre trying to achieve with getting the right positive connotation. However, i think with your preferred method being first and more prominent this will achieve more clicks than the with watermark one

Comment: I think the word clean is superfluous and possibly confusing to some users. I would go with "Save photo" or just "Save", and then "Save with watermark"

Comment: @DaveHaigh , Might be true, you are the second person to tell me that, I'll re-think about the word clean tomorrow, good catch !

Comment: Dont discount changing tactics as per my answer suggestions. Maybe after testing out this approach, or test on a subset on users. After tapping "Save photo" they are redirected to an in app purchase screen - include with watermark on there for users not willing at all to pay. You don't want to lose those users who may upgrade later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comments I thought I would post a mockup to explain.

---

**If you maintain your current workflow then I would use the following:**

- A prominent "Save"/"Save Photo" button first (Directs to in app
  purchase content)
- A secondary level "Save with watermark" button
- The in app purchase content should also explain somewhere that they can
  still save photos for free but with watermark (this is for users who aren't ready to purchase yet and whom you don't want to lose completely)
- Retain the save with watermark button on the in app purchase page or offer the ability to go back and choose that option instead (this is also for users who aren't ready to purchase yet and whom you don't want to lose completely)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I agree with comment by @jazZRo to your previous [question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/93203/giving-positive-negative-connotation-to-two-textual-options-buttons) that it is better to include price to first button. Thus you can avoid user frustration by clearly showing the options. However, the decision is yours.

Possible wordings for the buttons:

- `Save pure image ($00.00)`
- `Save pure ($00.00)`
- `Save clean image ($00.00)`
- `Save clean ($00.00)`
- `Save tagged image (free)`
- `Save tagged (free)`
- `Save with watermark (free)`

Comment: Hey umcdwarf, Thank you you for replying! I've updated the orginal question, so we can focus on the content. Tho, in your answer we give the free options even more positing effect, dosent we? saying it's free?

Comment: I saw the samples, they are great. But i'll try to change your mind set a bit. I'm trying to pass the feeling, which saving without watermark, is better than saving with. Our problem is that "with" has positive connotation while "without" has negative. With your great samples, it just mark even more that the "free" version is better, which most likley will cause the user to click this option. Can we try to come up with samples which improve the above? :) :)

Comment: I understand the point regarding connotations, but can't dispute related marketing implications, since my knowledge is limited. However, I believe it is important to provide transparent information, so that you avoid any confusion and broken user expectations.


Your call-to-action is well formatted to catch attention and be perceived more positively, but `Export tag free` text can mislead the user. The 'free' word is most likely to be understood as the option without charge, leading to frustration. Including price, on the other hand, will eliminate any misunderstanding regarding that.

Comment: (continuing previous comment, due to the limit)
The option for watermark is less emphasized, and users will most probably know that the watermark is, or at least see the difference between the alternatives to understand the downside. 

P.S. Just understood that `free` text for option with watermark is redundant as long as the price is included to call-to-action.

Comment: i see your point. It's Apple recommendation is as well. So basically stay transparent?  If so, using the word "Watermark" as is? I mean, it still leave us with a problem regarding the connotation. If we do leave price - we need to make the paid option looks more "sensible" than the second one. For example : writing 1) Save with watermark(1$). 2)Save without watermark(free). I would def go to options 2. So the real challenge is two make the free options negative compared to the paid one.

Comment: Hey umc, I've updated my question with another version. Would love to hear your thoughts!

Comment: Looks good, I like it :)

Comment: Thank you! Do you think the word "CLEAN" fits in? I mean, i'm not native english speaker so i have no idea if it's in the right context. You think it's fine?

Comment: Seems well enough, though I'm not a native speaker either. The only problem I can think of is that user might confuse 'clean' with unmodified picture without any filters, but don't know how to resolve that or would it even be the issue.

Comment: I'm releasing the app this week, i'll share my analytics after a few days of testing. We can see the results

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider an alternative solution entirely.

Allow your users to edit > save **seamlessly**. Keep the UX enjoyable and decision free i.e. don't risk confusing or annoying the user when it comes to saving a photo every time they do so.

What if a user doesn't understand what a watermark is for example?

Instead, just allow them to save away without any questions. As long as the preview clearly shows your watermark on the photo then they wont be surprised when it appears on the saved photo.

Now, after the photo has been saved away, you could direct them to a page or prompt within the app to 'inform' them that there is a way to save photos without a watermark. Then offer a link off to the in app purchase. I would even consider offering a 'Don't tell me again option' to this, and then clearly indicate where they can go to find the upgrade option if they change their mind in the future.

This way you **don't interrupt their workflow of editing and saving with the 'upgrade' option.**

It also allows them to save a few photos with your watermark on so that when they are told there is an option to get rid of this they will more likely understand what it is you are referring to and even be tempted because they have seen the effect of not having the upgrade.

### Key points:

- Let them experience the free option first so the upgrade makes sense
- Ask to upgrade at appropriate times - don't interrupt basic workflow
  if not necessary

Comment: Hey Dave. Thank you for  this great answer. A few things i'd like to mention. I would 100% took this approach in case this page wouldn't be my main source of income from the app. In others words. In the balance between great UX, to be a bit of interrupting to greaten the IAP rate, i unfortunately have to choose at the second option.Another aspect, is that after the user already saved the image, i think the chances i'll re-save it after unlocking is even worse, cuz we make him make the same action twice, and now days people just starve for speed. Tho from UX(no business) model. thats great way!

Comment: a question thats popped up from the second answer here. What are your thoughts? If we do leave price - we need to make the paid option looks more "sensible" than the second one. For example : writing 1) Save with watermark(1$). 2)Save without watermark(free). I would def go to options 2. So the real challenge is two make the free options negative compared to the paid one.

Comment: Hey Dave, I've added an updated version, Would love to hear your thoughts.

Comment: Hey Dave, what would your thoughts on this topic :)